# QGIS project with integrated images

Tags: qgis, shapefile, fields-attributes, image

I would like to know if anyone knows how to incorporate images as attributes in a QGIS project, and that these are displayed even if the folder containing the project and the source files (shapes, images, etc.) change location.

I know how it is done to show the image, but when sending the project, the other person can not visualize the images in the attributes.

For reference guide with the following video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1hcZPNL9yb8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the 2.14 QGIS version have been implemented the *External resource* as widget for field edit. You could see a detailed description [here](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog214/#feature-external-resource-widget)

From Layer Properties --> Fields --> Edit Widget --> “External resource”

[image]